# Rails: Using loops inside a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this project I'm working on where I have a checklist.  This checklist has an event_id, and then 2 fields for each task that much be done, one for the user_id that completed it, and one for the date.  First what I do is grab all the checklists, which gives me an acitverecord::relation of all the checklists.  Then I want to get only the completed checklists.

```
def index
    @check_lists = CheckList.joins(:booking).joins(:contract)

    @check_lists = @check_lists.complete if params[:status] == "complete"
    @check_lists = @check_lists.incomplete if params[:status] == "incomplete"

end
```

My problem is once I call the @check_lists.complete, does it automatically give me the array in the scope in the model?  Would I have to pass something in the method to get the array and run through it?  Then once I have the activerecord::relation how do I run a loop through it?

```
scope :complete, {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`scope :complete, -> { where(complete: true) }`

for example, would give you an ActiveRecord::Relation. This would be the same as `CheckList.where(complete: true)`. You can convert this relation to an array of results using `all`.

```
CheckList.complete #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
CheckList.complete.all #=> Array
```

In Rails 4, `all` will return an ActiveRecord::Relation as well, so it will be necessary to use `to_a` to convert it to an array, but for now `all` will return an Array.

Comment: Ok do I have to turn in to an array in order to loop through it in the scope?  I can't just do complete: true, because there are multiple fields that could be true, and I have to check to see if those fields are even a valid task. So basically I need to get to the scope having the relation or array and then loop through each item and determine myself if they are complete or not.

Comment: If you can't do it within the query, then yes. But you can also call `.each` on a relation and it will automatically convert it into an Array. In many cases, a Relation will act similarly to an array.

Comment: .each turns it into an array too.  Basically whats happening is I have a checklist that has 4 task, and that is video_check, audio_check, operator_check, and console_check.  So I need to check if each one is true, but  not all checklists will need all 4.  I also need to check to see if the video, auido, operator, and console are paid for with the 'event_id' (foreign key) before I check it.  I don't mind trying it a different way, but I cant think of one to get the job done that I need.